# Horizontal scroll inside section using fullpage js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I'm trying to add custom slider in the section which has slides, I'm using [Fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) plugin, I searched for this but cannot find anything clear, only vertical scroll bar is allowed, but not horizontal .. Is there any way to do this ? the fullpage js plugin using also slimscroll js when to set `scrollOverflow` `true` . [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p1x027Lm/) Code

// HTML

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="slide"> Slide 1 </div>
        <div class="slide"> Slide 2 </div>
        <div class="slide"> Slide 3 </div>
        <div class="slide"> Slide 4 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

// JS

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor : ['#ccc', '#456'],
});
```

Comment: The plugin only provides mouse wheel scroll for vertical sections.

Comment: +1 Have you find solution for this? I also tried to find it a lot, but no success. Would be thankful if you can provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code for horizontal scrolling with mousewheel (Note: This does not work properly with touchpad scrolling. More than 1 slide get scrolled in that case. Also, I do not have any vertical scrolling slider, only horizontal ones)

```
$('#fullpage').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event, delta) {
    if(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
      fullpage_api.moveSlideLeft();
    } else {
      fullpage_api.moveSlideRight();
    }
});
```